Powershell Function returning directory object instead of string
I am writing a powershell function that takes 2 parameters to check to see if a directory exists. If the directory exists then loop until the directory doesn't exist by adding a counter at the end of the folder and create the directory. Once a directory that doesn't exist is found, then return the new subfolder.
function Check-PatientDirectory{
    param (
            [string]$rootDirectoryName,
            [string]$subDirectoryName
        )
    # Initialize a counter
    $counter = 1

    # Store the original directory path
    $newSubDirectoryName = $subDirectoryName

    $testDirectoryPath = "$($rootDirectoryName)$($newSubDirectoryName)"
    
    # Loop until a directory with a unique name is found
    while (Test-Path -Path $testDirectoryPath) {
        # Increment the counter
        $counterString = $counter.ToString("D4")
        $testDirectoryPath = "$($rootDirectoryName)$($newSubDirectoryName)_$($counterString)\"
        $counter++
    }

    New-Item -Path $testDirectoryPath -ItemType Directory

    Return $newSubDirectoryName 
 }

Here is the code in the main body where I call the function:
#Check Patient Subfolder
            $outputLocation = "C:\Temp\"
            $test = "test_folder"
            $newSubDirectory = Check-PatientDirectory -rootDirectoryName $outputLocation -subDirectoryName $test 

            $outputLocation = "$($newSubDirectory)"
            
            Write-Host $outputLocation
      

The output is
C:\Temp\test_folder_0001 test_folder

When debugging, it looks like the function is returning a directory object. I provided a screenshot of the variable.

I want the function to return the subdirectory that was created. I am not sure why the function is not returning the subDirectory as a string.

Solution is to assign the output from New-Item to $null -> $null = New-Item.... You also probably want to return $testDirectoryPath since that is the constructed and created path

The issue with your code is that New-Item produces output that is not being captured or redirected. Solution can be to assign its output to $null or pipe to Out-Null (there are other ways too):
# this
$null = New-Item -Path $testDirectoryPath -ItemType Directory
# or this
New-Item -Path $testDirectoryPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

You could also just remove the return $newSubDirectoryName and re-use the output from New-Item expanding on .FullName (you also most likely want to return $testDirectoryPath in your actual code since that is the newly created folder).
function New-PatientDirectory {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $RootDirectoryName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $SubDirectoryName
    )

    # Initialize a counter
    $counter = 1

    # Store the original directory path
    $base = Join-Path $RootDirectoryName $SubDirectoryName

    # Loop until a directory with a unique name is found
    do {
        # Increment the counter
        $path = "${base}_$($counter.ToString('D4'))"
        $counter++
    }
    while (Test-Path -Path $path)

    # output the absolute path
    (New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory).FullName
}

